# Good pattern for building Lucene indexes on an application server and copying to multiple web servers

Tags: lucene.net, lucene

We are considering an architecture where an application rebuilds (often) a large number of Lucene indexes that we are using.  The last task in the rebuild would be to use a file share or FTP to copy that rebuilt index OVER the last index.

I'm a bit concerned about what happens if an end user is searching against that index during the time that we are copying a new index in.

Anyone have any thoughts, experiences, better patterns to achieve this?  I'm familiar with SOLR and that would be one way to go, not as familiar with Zoie from LinkedIn.  I would prefer to avoid both at this stage and go with our homegrown, fairly simple, 'just rebuild it and copy it on top' approach.

Comment: Just met about this and considering another approach where we have a dedicated server that updates the indexes in place and serves as the API endpoint for querying the indexes, thus no file copy issues.

Comment: Just to point out you wouldnt need to copy over the entire index, just new segments. On the node the files are being copied on, you simply re-open you readers to see changes to the index.

Comment: Are the servers load balanced (active/passive)? Can you temporarily shut connections off to the server and from the server?

Comment: @BartCzernicki  no we can't, and we rebuild indexes pretty much all day, so needa  pattern where we can rebuild in place as we write to them all day

Answer (score 0):

One option is to directly store the indexes directly in something like AppFabric cache rather than on the file system. Another is to create your own implementation of directory that kinda wraps around FSDirectory and monitors a separate staging directory and if it sees new indexes that are ready, blocks subsequent calls until it copies them over.